# Saving files with net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

I am looking for a way to save a uploaded file in .NET core v3.1

I have this code:

```cs
public async Task<bool> SaveFile(IFormFile file)
{
    try
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(FilesPath, file.FileName);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

It creates the file correctly, but it always creates a 0 bytes file.

Comment: `await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);` You missed `await` keyword

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `await` when calling `CopyToAsync()`

Also `file.Length` can be 0 so it is good to check for that.

```cs
public async Task<bool> SaveFile(IFormFile file)
{
    try
    {
        if (formFile.Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var filePath = Path.Combine(FilesPath, file.FileName);

        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

[Docs for File uploads in .net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads)

Comment: Hi, thanks to answer my question but i still have same trouble. The file is created correctly but it has 0 Bytes.(I loaded a file which size is 1MB)